# p5.js mousePressed event returns Undefined

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I cant get mousePressed to console log the MouseEvent. I'm not even sure if having it in the setup function is the right place?

https://codesandbox.io/embed/withered-monad-jrhyw

```
import React from 'react';
import Sketch from 'react-p5';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const setup = (p5: any) => {
    canvas = p5.createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    canvas.mouseWheel((e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log(e); // Wheel Event
    });

    canvas.mousePressed((e: MouseEvent) => {
      console.log(e); // Undefined
    });

  };

  const draw = (p5: any) => {
    p5.background(50);
    p5.fill(0);
    p5.rect(25, 25, 50, 50);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export { App };
```

Answer (score 1):

The [readme](https://github.com/Gherciu/react-p5) of the `react-p5` library indicates that you should use the `mousePressed` method as a prop, so try and define it outside of `setup` and then pass it:

```
const mp = (e: MouseEvent) => {
  console.log(e);
})

<Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} mousePressed={mp}/>
```

Nevertheless, I did try defining several other methods inside of `setup` and all seemed to work normally; `mousePressed` was the only one that required to be passed as a prop.

Comment: Thanks for this, I now get a new error `Type '(e: MouseEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(p5: P5) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'p5' are incompatible.
    Type 'P5' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 42 more.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(26, 2): The expected type comes from property 'mousePressed' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<SketchProps, any, any>> & Readonly<SketchProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'`

Comment: Huh... I just ran your codesandbox link and tested passing `mp2` and didn't get any errors. In any case it might have to do with the way `react-p5` handles the methods; if you check the source code you'll see that, for some reason, it passes the reference to p5 as an argument to all the events: `this.props[event](p)`. And, now that I check, the thing that gets logged in `mp2` is a p5 object and not a mouseEvent. Maybe check another wrapper library?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question on opened GitHub Issue in order to use only one channel to track this issue and resolve it. [Github Issue #16](https://github.com/Gherciu/react-p5/issues/16)